# PHP DOM Xpath - how to get a single element

Tags: php, dom, xpath

```
<?php
$html = new DOMDocument();
$html->loadHtmlFile( 'report.html' );
$xpath = new DOMXPath( $html );

$results = $xpath->evaluate('/html/body/div/table[2]/tr/td[3]');
foreach ($results as $result)
{
  {
    echo $result->nodeValue."\r\n";
  }
}
?>
```

returns

```
GTkio94312
10/24/2011 10:21:45
01:19:46
```

I tried

```
echo $result->nodeValue->item[0];
```

to only get

```
GTkio94312
```

but it returns an empty line. Where's my fault?

Comment: What value will return your function by *echo $result->nodeValue->item[1];* - it is possible that *$results* has more then 3 items (for example it can have empty text node before *GTkio94312*)

Comment: why don't you use $results = $xpath->query('/html/body/div/table[2]/tr/td[3]')->item(0); item is a function, not an array.

Answer (score 2):

`->nodValue` returns a simple string, not an object. Any given node has only a single nodeValue, so there's no `->item[...]` subobject/subarray to retrieve other data from.

```
$results->item(0)->nodeValue;  // correct - nodevalue of first result node in results object
       ^---note the S
$result->item(0)->... // incorrect - result is a single node
```

xpath's query() returns a DOMNodeList. Doing a foreach on that list returns the individual DOMNode objects that were found by the xpath query. Each DOMNode has a single nodeValue attribute, which is the node's contents as a string.

Comment: echo $results->item(0)->nodeValue;
redirected to a file results in
GTkio94312GTkio94312GTkio94312